# How to take only the last 3 digits from the year

Tags: c#, date, datetimepicker

I have the windows form dateTimePicker. I want to take only the last 3 digits from the year for example: if the chosen date is 01.01.2016 i want it to be read as 0101016
The code i am trying to use wont work

```
            string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("ddMMyyy");
```

When i put ddMMyyyy it looks like this: 01012016 what is ok, 
when i put ddMMyy it gives this 010116 what is also ok
But i need it to give me the last 3 digits from the year and when i put ddMMyyy it wont work :/

Comment: You will have to assign datetime.ToString("ddMMyyyy") to a variable, then manually remove what you need.

Comment: `string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("ddMMyyyy").Remove(4,1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateTime dateTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;
string theDate = dateTime.ToString("ddMM") + dateTime.Year.ToString("D4").Substring(1);
```

Comment: .NET only supports up to year 9999 currently so this is an acceptable solution.

Comment: @dustmouse I think Daniel was referring to dates before 1000

Comment: Yes, but I've now updated it to work with dates < 1000.

Comment: Would seem weird to me given the requirements that the first digit be lobbed off, that it would be used with any year below 1000 AD.  Even above 1000 AD there is still ambiguity.  This date format is like an inverted Y2K bug.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Substring to get the Year from the (n-3)-th digit onwards for year >= 1000 like this:

```
DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;
string y = dt.Year.ToString();
string val = dt.ToString("ddMM") + y.Substring(y.Length > 3 ? y.Length - 3 : 0);
```